# Postgres 9.2 beta for Suse SLES

Tags: postgresql, rpm, opensuse, sles

I am searching the internets high and low, but can't find any Postgres 9.2 beta versions for any SLES versions. Can I take some Fedora RPM or similiar, or can someone tell me how to find the RPMs on the internets?

Thanks for any link or hint.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to run a *beta* release of Postgres? Assuming there is, is there a reason you want to do so but building it from source/rolling your own package isn't an acceptable option?  Postgres betas see pretty active development - I wouldn't want to be waiting on a vendor update for one...

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been discussed at [SuSE Forums](https://forums.suse.com/showthread.php?1120-PostgreSQL-on-SLES11), you have to add repository and install postgresql92-server:

```
zypper ar http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/database:/postgresql/SLE_11_SP2/server:database:postgresql.repo
zypper install postgresql92-server
```

Answer (score 0):

http://software.opensuse.org/search

https://build.opensuse.org/search

http://rpm.pbone.net

http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/fedora/linux/updates/17/SRPMS/

http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/

Comment: Can I just use your Fedora RPMs on a Suse SLES system?

Comment: Using original Fedora binary RPM's is a bad idea - at least you will have problems with dependencies.
Take src.rpm from https://build.opensuse.org/search/search?search_text=postgresql&commit=Search&project=1&package=1&name=1&attribute=&advanced=on&issue_tracker=bnc+%28Novell+Bugzilla%29&issue_name= and recompile with new sources. You need some experience... Maybe there are some 9.2 files in suse buildservice.